# Remove OS, but keep documents

Tags: macos, hard-drive, ssd

Yesterday I installed an SSD in my MacBook and kept my original HDD with a "data doubler" (replaces the DVD-drive with a hard-drive bay).

That means I have my OS (and applications) on both my SSD and HDD. Is it possible to get rid of the OS on the HDD?

I think that removing everything but the *~/users*-folder from the HDD should solve this problem, right? If not, what is the best solution to achieve this?

Comment: It's impossible for us to know if you have stashed data somewhere else besides the *~/users-folders*

Comment: Of course, I will find out before I permanently delete everything, but in theory (and if you only keep documents in your ~/users-folder), that would solve the "problem", right?

Comment: If you are fairly confident that you haven't moved data around manually, keeping just the `/User/*` folders should probably be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are fairly confident that you haven't moved data around manually, keeping just the `/User/*` folders should probably be enough.

Comment: Thanks, I just needed the confirmation if my idea would work!

Comment: FWIW, I have essentially the same user profile on OS X for 7 years now, and several times I reinstalled the OS, migrated to a different computer, or restored from Time Machine and often only restored or kept the user accounts (essentially `/Users/*`). Besides drivers, globally installed applications, and global settings (e.g. printer configuration), i.e. the obvious candidates, nothing was ever missing afterwards. cc @Rvervuurt